# Is the CLOCKS_PER_SEC value "wrong" inside a virtual machine

Tags: c, linux, time, virtual-machine

I code inside a virtual machine( Linux Ubuntu) that's installed on a windows.
According to [this page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock), the CLOCKS_PER_SEC value in the  library on Linux should always be 1 000 000. 

When I run this code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    while (1)
       printf("%f, %f \n\n", (double)clock(), (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

The first value is 1 000 000 as it should be, however, the value that should show the number of seconds does NOT increase at the normal pace (it takes between 4 and 5 seconds to increase by 1)

Is this due to my working on a virtual machine? How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't use the value returned by `clock` by itself, it doesn't make any sense. You have to use a difference between two calls.

Comment: `clock` returns a `clock_t`. This is not necessarily a `double` `%f` requires.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is a code meant to test out. I look at the units digit and how it changes over time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected.

The `clock()` function does not return the wall time (the time that real clocks on the wall display).  It returns the amount of CPU time used by your program.  If your program is not consuming every possible scheduler slice, then it will increase slower than wall time, if your program consumes slices on multiple cores at the same time it can increase faster.

So if you call `clock()`, and then `sleep(5)`, and then call `clock()` again, you'll find that `clock()` has barely increased at all.  Even though `sleep(5)` waits for 5 real seconds, it doesn't consume any CPU, and CPU usage is what `clock()` measures.

If you want to measure wall clock time you will want `clock_gettime()` (or the older version `gettimeofday()`).  You can use `CLOCK_REALTIME` if you want to know the civil time (e.g. "it's 3:36 PM") or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` if you want to measure time intervals.  In this case, you probably want `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    struct timespec start, now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    while (1) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
        printf("Elapsed: %f\n",
               (now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
               1e-9 * (now.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec));
    }
}
```

The usual proscriptions against using busy-loops apply here.